# Multiplying scientific notation and modifying the precision in awk

Tags: csv, awk

I have csv files and I need to scale the first column of csv file with value 1.3. I am able to scale the first column of csv file with value 1.3 using awk. Here is the one line code which I  have used for scaling:

```
$ awk -F, '{$1=$1*1.3;print}' OFS=, input.csv > output.csv
```

Now the problem is that after scaling, I want the result upto 9 or 10 decimal places but I am getting upto 5 decimal places.

input.csv file format:

```
9.876160000E-07 , 6.5940E-03
9.876180000E-07 , 4.0718E-03
```

output.csv file format (after running awk command):

```
1.2839e-06,      6.5940E-03
1.2839e-06,      4.0718E-03
```

Expected Output.csv file format:

```
1.28390080e-06,  6.5940E-03
1.28390340e-06,  4.0718E-03
```

What to change in awk command to get the expected result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this, using `sprintf`:

```
$ awk '{$1=sprintf("%.8e",$1*1.3);print}' file
1.28390080e-06 , 6.5940E-03
1.28390340e-06 , 4.0718E-03
```

Comment: it is not displaying the second column, so i did this change in the line to display the second column also -->

awk -F '{$1=sprintf("%.8e",$1*1.3);print}' OFS=, input.csv > output.csv

Comment: I didn't bother to `-F,`, apparently, so that might cause problems if there is no space before the `,`...